# What is causing Views to consistently but intermittently not find a view provided by the Advanced Forum module?

Tags: 7, views

I'm getting a frequent, intermittent error from the Advanced Forum module that causes a 500 error when it occurs (WSOD). On production, it's happening about 20 times per hour, on probably 2-3% of all forum page loads per hour. It is *consistently intermittent*. Locally, I cannot consistently reproduce the error, but it does occur.

The error is on

> Line 232 o f sites/all/modules/contrib/advanced_forum/includes/core-overrides.inc`:
>
> Call to undefined method stdClass::preview()

The problem lies with the advanced_forum_get_topics() function:

```
function advanced_forum_get_topics($tid, $sortby, $forum_per_page, $sort_form = TRUE) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  drupal_add_feed('taxonomy/term/' . $tid . '/feed', 'RSS - ' . check_plain($term->name));

  // Views handles this page
  $view = views_get_view('advanced_forum_topic_list');
  $view->sort_form = $sort_form;

  return $view->preview('default', array($tid));

}
```

Essentially views_get_view() fails to find the view and the object isn't created as expected on the return line. So the problem seems to lie with Views occasionally not knowing the view exists. This makes me think it's a hook problem.

Where it starts to get odd are the implementations of hook_views_default_views() and hook_views_plugins(). According to views.api.php hook_views_default_views() should be in a file called MODULENAME.views_default.inc and hook_views_plugins() should be in a file called MODULENAME.views.inc. However, both files are in the MODULENAME.views.inc file.

From views.api.php:

- `hook_views_plugins()`
  This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be auto-loaded.
  MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.
- `hook_views_default_views()`
  This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views_default.inc and it will be auto-loaded.   MODULENAME.views_default.inc must be in the directory specified by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.

I tried splitting up these routines into the seemingly correct files. This caused Views to consistently find the Advanced Forum view (as indicated that it appeared in the Views GUI list) but not see the plug-in. The pages in Advanced Forum ran fine, but the views were blank because they referenced a style plugin provided by Advanced Forum that Views was no longer seeing.

I assume I'm missing something about Views hooks, but I'm totally stumped.

- Stack: Drupal 7, Views (7.x-3.3), CTools (7.x-1.0), Advanced Forum (7.x-2.0)
- PHP FPM, APC, nginx, Redis
- I didn't find anything helpful in this [d.o issue](http://drupal.org/node/1104832)

**UPDATE 1**: While I have not solved the root cause, it does appear that disabling Redis and reverting to Drupal's default database-based cache storage mechanism stops the problem from occuring.

**UPDATE 2**: I can reliably replicate the issue on local by doing a `flushall` in Redis. The first page load of looking at a forum listing will fatal out. <s>The second page load (and all subsequent) work fine</s>. UPDATE: I have to hit the admin Views listing page to clear the error.

**UPDATE 3**: On further troubleshooting the issue appears to be caused by the Views cache not properly being rebuilt after a cache clear, only when using Redis. The issue does not occur when reverting to standard Drupal cache. When the issue occurs only 2-4 cache entries exists for Views, as opposed 100+ when the cache is properly built. Visiting the admin views list page causes the cache to be fully built and the issue does not occur. I need to verify if hitting any View view page causing the issue, or just the advanced forum view.

**UPDATE 4**: A helpful user on IRC has suggested this might be a problem related to Views cache race condition issues: [853864](http://drupal.org/node/853864), [1102252](http://drupal.org/node/1102252)

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue in the Views, Ctools, or Advanced Forum queue? It looks to me like the question at hand is *does Views or Advanced Forum currently support redis?* As far as I am aware of, Views uses a relational query language (SQL) to construct it's displays. I am not sure how well that would play out with Redis (a key-value store). This is not really an answer, but then, I personally don't know if there's an answer to that. I also recommend that you reach out the drupal IRC channels for this question. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting setup you have there.

Comment: I'm only using Redis as a drop-in replacement for Drupal's cache backend, so it *should* be transparent to Views. I posted to D.o without luck. http://drupal.org/node/1110688

Comment: @amateurbarista It's Pantheon Drupal.

Comment: What does your pantheon log file say about those pages of WSOD? Are you running APC locally?

Comment: The Pantheon log is where I get the "Call to undefined method stdClass::preview()" error I mention above. I do not have APC locally. This issue now appears to be with Redis and Views. It appears that the Views cache takes two page loads to be fully created, and won't often run until the second page load.

Comment: Are you in a position to try other cache backends?  That could potentially identify whether you are having a problem with Views or with Redis.

Comment: @mpd I am in. As I mentioned, it works with Drupal standard cache backend.

Comment: @Justin, I meant cache backends other than Redis or MySQL, eg APC, memcache, or Mongo.

Comment: @mpd - Sorry, misunderstood. I am not, no. Pantheon supports only Redis.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as XDebug or Zend Debugger to troubleshoot the problem line-by-line? With a debugger you'll find what is the problem for sure!

Comment: You're also missing a call to `$view->pre_execute()` before rendering the view.

Comment: Any updates to this question?

Comment: This could be related to apc cache too since the problem is related to missing class. Could you please post your cache settings.

Comment: I had the same problem - before I rand `$view->execute()`, I had a `$view->pre_execute()` command.  When I removed this, it stopped happening.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you found the right answer from the IRC.  "Consistently intermittent" in my experience is when there are two sources filling the cache.  Most common is when you have a development site and a staging/production site on different code bases but same database.  The drupal-provided caches that I have read code for connect to the database, so routing/function information that is cached will cross contaminate.  Hitting the admin/modules page will refresh the module cache and locations, hitting the admin/views listing page clears your error because it refreshes the site's understanding of views from the perspective of your site instead of the perspective of whatever is conflicting with you.

If you have server admin ability, change the password to your site's database and the password in your settings.php, and see what breaks.  Your listings should stop being corrupted and what is tampering with them should break ... unless it is directly connected to your site and using your settings.php file.

Also, check to make sure there are not multiple installations of the views module in your docroot.